# Ngrok invalid host header

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ngrok

I am using ngrok to expose my react app. Due to an "invalid host header", I have re-written the host header using `ngrok http 3000 -host-header="localhost:3000"`, which works fine.

The problem that I am encountering is that when I added in my backend node.js server, I added multiple tunnels to my ngrok.yml file :

```
    tunnels:
  first:
    addr: 3000
    proto: http    
  second:
    addr: 5000
    proto: http
```

Now, to expose react & node.js, I am using

```
ngrok start --all
```

But now I am back to the issue where I am getting the invalid host header on my front end. How do I rewrite my host header for my front end with the "ngrok start --all"?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve this issue for others who do encounter a similar situation.

In the ngrok.yml file, include `host_header: "localhost:3000"`